# core plot stacked graph crossing top border

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-plot

I'm trying to create a stacked graph using core plot.i have followed [this](http://www.gilthonwe.com/2012/06/09/stacked-bar-chart-coreplot-ios/) tutorial.I have a UISlider on sliding i'm updating my graph.The issue i'm facing is my top value for y-axis is touching top border(As in the screen shot). As per my requirement in need to round off the highest value to next 10th value so that my graph doesn't touch the borders.
On changing my slider value the x and y axis should also get refresh,i'm doing it by regenerating plot but it takes a lot of memory.
Any idea how can i achieve these requirement ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't recreate the whole graph every time the values change. Call `-reloadData` on the graph to refresh the plot data and set the `xRange` and `yRange` of the plot space to change the scale of the axes.

Comment: Thank you @eric for your reply,-reloadData it worked, and for Y Axis i'm using CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic ,i'm not getting the last top value as in the screen shot i have given,you can see last value it's showing is 20000 but i need to show the updated value (for above image it is 25000) and also my graph is getting little trimmed at top